# Office Web App server high memory usage!

Tags: owa

My OWA server memory is 12GB. Recently, it's always high memory usage at > 96%.
So it is causing PowerPoint documents cannot load and promptly an error:

[image]

I've temporary workaround by restart web service on OWA server, then it normal.

How can I prevent this issue in future?

Thanks guys,

Comment: Good question - I have also the same problem and I am also managing by restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Request additional RAM for your VMs or scale out by adding an additional server to your Office Web Apps farm.